# Avoiding void pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, void-pointers

I am implementing my own programming language in C++11.

One of the datatypes I've designed is the `Token` class. It is meant to store a token read from the source file, with the content of the token, it's type, and the line at which it was encountered.

A token can be either a single-character symbol, a lenghtful string, a number, or a name. So it needs to be able to store different data types, either a character for symbols, a double for numbers, and a std::string for names and strings.

The way I'm implementing this is by storing that value in a void pointer, and by adding an attribute of a custome enum which helps understand what type should you cast that void pointer to.

Of course I could have a class for each of those subtypes of Token, but I would at some point anyway need to store all of them as a `Token*`, which means I will still need to have an enum which helps me know what type should I cast that `Token*` to.

Here's the actual code for it:

```
enum token_type {
    symbol,
    number,
    name,
    string
};

struct Token {
    void* value = nullptr;
    token_type type;
    unsigned int line;

    Token(void* new_value, token_type new_type, unsigned int new_line):
        value(new_value), type(new_type), line(new_line)
        {}

    ~Token() {
        switch (type) {
            case symbol:
                delete (char*) value;
                break;
            case number:
                delete (double*) value;
                break;
            case name:
            case string:
                delete (std::string*) value;
        }
    }
};
```

What is a good design pattern to implement this which avoids the use of void pointers and (possibly) enums? Everyone keeps telling me that this design is wrong, but I got no suggestions on how to actually improve this situation, so I asked here.

Comment: did you have had a look at `boost::variant`?

Comment: Hmm, well most compilers are drowning in void pointers, so I wouldn't say using them is necessarily wrong, however since you know the datatypes you'll need, you could look into using a variant or similar data type.

Comment: @Hayt not sure I'm able to use boost. I'm working on Android using a Linux emulator, and boost isn't there. Maybe I should manually download it. I'm still not sure on its portability.

Comment: You could try. Boost has a list of which compilers it can build. If you can get access to C++17 you have std::variant in there.

Comment: @Hayt just tried. Yes, I can use the g++ compile flag for c++17 (`-std=c++1z`). Can you build an answer on that?

Comment: @user6245072 you might want to check the c++17 implementation has `std::variant` implemented--frequently with future standards there's only a partial implementation that grows more complete over time. libstd++ only has it in version 7.

Comment: @user6245072 you should check if you can include the `<variant>` header first. Just the compiler flags may not help you

Comment: @Hayt and.... it doesn't. No `variant` found .-.

Comment: You could have four internal const pointers and use only one of them in any given instance. Or you could derive four tokens (`SymbolToken`, `NumberToken`,...) from the abstract `Token`. What are you trying for?

Comment: @user6245072 I thought so. I was just looking for a compiler to test my code with and ran into this issue too :( . So you can try boost (compile it locally) or with what skypjack answererd.

Comment: @Beta as I said, even with multiple, derived classes I will need to store them in the form of a `Token*` so Token will always have to have a way to know which type that Token* should be casted to.

Comment: `virtual token_type Token::getType() const = 0;`.

Comment: @Hayt `compile it locally` how?

Comment: @user6245072 if you don't have boost available you can compile boost from it's source on your compiler and link against it to use the functionality

Comment: @Hayt unfortunately I see no way of doing this on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can erase the type as it follows:

```
class Token {
    using Deleter = void(void*);
    using Func = void(*)(void*);

    template<typename T>
    static void proto(void *ptr) {
        T t = static_cast<T*>(ptr);
        // do whatever you want here...
        // ... or use specializations.
    }

public:
    template<typename T>
    Token(T* value):
        value{value, [](void *ptr) { delete static_cast<T*>(ptr); }},
        func{&proto<T>}
    {}

    void operator()() {
        func(value.get());
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<void, Deleter> value;
    Func func;
};
```

The instance will be correctly deleted for the smart pointer *knows* the type.
In a similar manner, by means of a bunch of specializations of `proto`, you can define different operations for the multiple types you want to deal with.

It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

struct A {};
struct B {};

class Token {
    using Deleter = void(*)(void*);
    using Func = void(*)(void*);

    template<typename T>
    static void proto(void *ptr);

public:
    template<typename T>
    Token(T *value): 
        value{value, [](void *ptr) { delete static_cast<T*>(ptr); }},
        func{&proto<T>}
    {}

    void operator()() {
        func(value.get());
    }

private:
    std::unique_ptr<void, Deleter> value;
    Func func;
};

template<>
void Token::proto<A>(void *ptr) {
    A *a = static_cast<A*>(ptr);
    // use a
    (void)a;
    std::cout << "A" << std::endl;
}

template<>
void Token::proto<B>(void *ptr) {
    B *b = static_cast<B*>(ptr);
    // use b
    (void)b;
    std::cout << "B" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    Token token{new A};
    token();
}
```

Comment: Whaaaaaat? Could you add just _a few_ (I mean a lot) more comments? `using` inside a class is completely new to me. Also how would I use this?

Comment: @user6245072 `using` declarations... Never heard them. Well, nice, I'm adding more details in a few minutes.

Comment: Wait, no, I know them, I just never saw them inside a class. Also is `value{value)` a mistake?

Comment: too much informations all at once ahah I need to read a lot of documentation T.T

Comment: This is a type-erased nullary function object. I'm not sure how this solves OP's problem of a token that can be one of 4 types.

Comment: @Barry Added a minimal example. It's a matter of specialize proto for its types.

Comment: I liked Barry's method more, but I'm going to use this because I habe no access to `variant` classes. It works, so yeah.

Comment: The only thing that confuses me is: why are you passing `void` as the first template parameter for `value`?

Comment: In the complete example, the 26th.

Comment: @user6245072 This one `std::unique_ptr<void, Deleter> value;`? `T` is a template parameter of the constructor, not of the class. Because of that, the data member knows nothing about it and you cannot use it here. This is more or less one of the basic concepts of the _type-erasure_.

Comment: One last thing. What are `(void)a;` and `(void)b;` meant to do?

Comment: @user6245072 Silent some warnings in the example. :-) ... If you use the variables, you can safely remove those lines.

Answer (score 2):

> A token can be either a single-character symbol, a lenghtful string, a number, or a name.

Whenever you have an object that can be one of many things, that's a sum type / disjoint union / variant. That directly maps into:

```
using Token = variant<char, std::string, int, Name>;
```

(where `variant` here is either [`boost::variant`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/variant/tutorial.html) or, new in C++1z, [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)). This is a class template that internally keeps track of which type it is and exposes it to you in a type-safe way.

> The way I'm implementing this is by storing that value in a void pointer, and by adding an attribute of a custome enum which helps understand what type should you cast that void pointer to.

Think of `variant` as doing basically that - except instead of a `void*`, a `variant` is a *value type*. It's copyable, moveable, assignable, value destructible. It owns its own data. If you read up on the Boost tutorial, it will explain how you can access the underlying storage in a type safe way.